# After applying a mirror and subsurf, there is a clear edge at mirror axis rather than a smooth overflow

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, mirror

[image: Model screenshot]

I've applied a mirror and then a subsurf to the model, however the mirror doesnt flow smoothly and instead there is a "seam" in the center as seen above. The modifier settings are shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the mirror modifier first? And you need to enable merge in the mirror modifier.

Comment: If you upload your file I can make a gif of how to do it. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Denis I had applied the mirror modifier first, however as you suggested hadn't clicked "merge". That fixed it